# How does plc4j Modbus switch to big endian

Tags: endianness, modbus-tcp, plc4x

My device only supports big-endian mode, plc4j uses little-endian by default, how does plc4j use big-endian mode

I can't find a solution now

Comment: Currently the modbus driver doesn't have a flag to switch the endianess. It's planned, but currently nobody has worked on it yet. However looking at the current code it seems that the diver actually is big-endian per default. So it should work.
Could you please try version 0.11.0 which we released a few weeks ago?